# How to pass custom object as input parameter to custom PS cmdlets?

Tags: powershell-2.0

"New-CustomTemplate" my custom PS cmdlet which takes .txt filepath as one of its parameter. Text file in turn contains custom object definition in JSON format.

Is there any way to pass custom object as one of the parameter to my PS cmdlet (New-CustomTemplate) rather than creating object structure inside local file and providing its 'filepath' as cmdlet's parameter? please suggest.

### Actual custom PS cmdlet:

```
New-CustomTemplate -TemplateName May1219 -FilePath "F:\test\customkvp.txt" -Owner John
```

### Expected:

```
New-CustomTemplate -TemplateName May1219 -KVP customKVPobject -Owner John
```

Comment: What is `customKVPobject`? What type is it?

Comment: Consider "customKVPobject"  as some custom c# complex/aggregated object.